# Small outline icons from illustrator to photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, icon

I had created 24x24 pixels size outline icons (width: 1 pixel) on
AI6 and I also used the Path/Outline stroke at the end. When I paste it as shape layer, smart object etc. to Photoshop it looks **fuzzy**.

The icon located in pixel perfect without any decimal value and
I didn't resize it in Photoshop.

What am I missing? could be that there is no way doing that for small icons?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you are caught in the trap of anti-aliasing. Your vectors get in between of pixels and Photoshop smooth them out. Here is two ways:

1. Turn on pixel grid (be sure you see any each pixel) and fix alignment of your vectors to grid
2. Turn on Pixel Preview <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> in Adobe Illustrator and fix shape there in "pixel view" exactly.

Comment: I'm trying to use the pixel view on AI and it looks better. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Small comment, also check if your artboards are placed on an exact pixels. If they are not, then AI adds extra anti-aliasing.